# How to achieve a scrolling like in FB profile where the left panel will stop scrolling when it reaches bottom, while the right can continue to scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scroll

I'm using Bootstrap 5 for my UI layouts, and I have 1 row and 2 columns for left and right.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    // This is the left side
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    // This is the right side
  </div>
</div>
```

Like in Facebook profile, I want both of it to be scrollable at the same time, but the left panel must stop once it reaches its bottom and the right panel can continue to scroll. How can I achieve that?

I have tried many ways like putting an overflow, tracking the scroll using jQuery and more but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row flex-nowrap">
        <div class="col-auto col-md-3 col-xl-2 px-sm-2 px-0 bg-dark vh-100 overflow-auto position-sticky top-0">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center align-items-sm-start px-3 pt-2 text-white min-vh-100">
                <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center pb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto text-white text-decoration-none">
                    <span class="fs-5 d-none d-sm-inline">Menu</span>
                </a>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-sm-auto mb-0 align-items-center align-items-sm-start" id="menu">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link align-middle px-0">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-house"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Home</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link align-middle px-0">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-house"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Home</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link align-middle px-0">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-house"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Home</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link align-middle px-0">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-house"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Home</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link align-middle px-0">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-house"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Home</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#submenu1" data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-speedometer2"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Dashboard</span> </a>
                        <ul class="collapse show nav flex-column ms-1" id="submenu1" data-bs-parent="#menu">
                            <li class="w-100">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Item</span> 1 </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Item</span> 2 </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-table"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Orders</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#submenu2" data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle ">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-bootstrap"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Bootstrap</span></a>
                        <ul class="collapse nav flex-column ms-1" id="submenu2" data-bs-parent="#menu">
                            <li class="w-100">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Item</span> 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Item</span> 2</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#submenu3" data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-grid"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Products</span> </a>
                            <ul class="collapse nav flex-column ms-1" id="submenu3" data-bs-parent="#menu">
                            <li class="w-100">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Product</span> 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Product</span> 2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Product</span> 3</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0"> <span class="d-none d-sm-inline">Product</span> 4</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link px-0 align-middle">
                            <i class="fs-4 bi-people"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Customers</span> </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <hr>
                <div class="dropdown pb-4">
                    <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center text-white text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownUser1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <img src="https://github.com/mdo.png" alt="hugenerd" width="30" height="30" class="rounded-circle">
                        <span class="d-none d-sm-inline mx-1">loser</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small shadow" aria-labelledby="dropdownUser1">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New project...</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col py-3">
            <h3>Left Sidebar with Submenus</h3>
            <p class="lead">
                An example 2-level sidebar with collasible menu items. The menu functions like an "accordion" where only a single 
                menu is be open at a time. While the sidebar itself is not toggle-able, it does responsively shrink in width on smaller screens.</p>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li><h5>Responsive</h5> shrinks in width, hides text labels and collapses to icons only on mobile</li>
                <li><h5>Responsive</h5> shrinks in width, hides text labels and collapses to icons only on mobile</li>
                <li><h5>Responsive</h5> shrinks in width, hides text labels and collapses to icons only on mobile</li>
                <li><h5>Responsive</h5> shrinks in width, hides text labels and collapses to icons only on mobile</li>
                <li><h5>Responsive</h5> shrinks in width, hides text labels and collapses to icons only on mobile</li>
                <li><h5>Responsive</h5> shrinks in width, hides text labels and collapses to icons only on mobile</li>
                <li><h5>Responsive</h5> shrinks in width, hides text labels and collapses to icons only on mobile</li>
                <li><h5>Responsive</h5> shrinks in width, hides text labels and collapses to icons only on mobile</li>
                <li><h5>Responsive</h5> shrinks in width, hides text labels and collapses to icons only on mobile</li>
                <li><h5>Responsive</h5> shrinks in width, hides text labels and collapses to icons only on mobile</li>
                <li><h5>Responsive</h5> shrinks in width, hides text labels and collapses to icons only on mobile</li>
                <li><h5>Responsive</h5> shrinks in width, hides text labels and collapses to icons only on mobile</li>
                <li><h5>Responsive</h5> shrinks in width, hides text labels and collapses to icons only on mobile</li>
                <li><h5>Responsive</h5> shrinks in width, hides text labels and collapses to icons only on mobile</li>
                <li><h5>Responsive</h5> shrinks in width, hides text labels and collapses to icons only on mobile</li>
                <li><h5>Responsive</h5> shrinks in width, hides text labels and collapses to icons only on mobile</li>
                <li><h5>Responsive</h5> shrinks in width, hides text labels and collapses to icons only on mobile</li>
                <li><h5>Responsive</h5> shrinks in width, hides text labels and collapses to icons only on mobile</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```